# select object by nested field's value and extract a first level field

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json:

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "rvbrc7y6a5d6xpz37av534zv3a",
    "templateUuid": "101",
    "trashed": "N",
    "createdAt": "2018-07-26T05:48:51Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-27T00:26:35Z",
    "changerUuid": "Y7WX2RXJ35GCLLERQA2T74CKNM",
    "itemVersion": 3,
    "vaultUuid": "awn3jry3oo55xdcfgs7bnlyioa",
    "overview": {
      "ps": 0,
      "title": "Env Vars - CSP 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "uuid": "xtf3vdsnw5ardldytwh6edihzu",
    "templateUuid": "001",
    "trashed": "N",
    "createdAt": "2013-10-15T01:29:57Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-11-22T20:57:47Z",
    "changerUuid": "Y7WX2RXJ35GCLLERQA2T74CKNM",
    "itemVersion": 1,
    "vaultUuid": "qmorozyspqhb26kr4z7nbt7hpy",
    "overview": {
      "URLs": [
        {
          "u": "https://example.com"
        }
      ],
      "ainfo": "*******@gmail.com",
      "ps": 72,
      "title": "https://example.com",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    }
  }
]
```

There are another ~500 objects in the array which I need to parse. Three of the objects have an `.overview.title` which contains the string "Env Vars".

Im trying to use `jq` to get the output to look like:

```
"rvbrc7y6a5d6xpz37av534zv3a", "Env Vars - CSP 1"
"another uuid", "Env Vars - CSP 2"
"yet another uuid", "Env vars - CSP n"
```

Ive tried a few different things including:

- `cat list.json | jq -c '.[] | .uuid, .overview.title'`
- `cat list.json | jq -c '.[].overview.title | select(contains("Env Var"))'`

And a lot of different variations of the above.
This is the first time Ive had to use `jq` in anger so it's pretty new to me. The `jq` doco wasn't very helpful tbh.

Would like to buy a clue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select objects where `.overview.title` contains `Env Vars`, extract `.uuid` out of them, make arrays of UUID and title pairs, and feed them to `@csv` filter.

```
.[]
| .overview.title as $t 
| select($t | index("Env Vars")) 
| [.uuid, $t]
| @csv
```

Note that you need to specify `-r`/`--raw-output` flag on the command line for jq to yield valid CSV.